# Tally Table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to create a bunch of data with Tally table in SQL (sql2008) and definitely need help.

First of all, I have this table which contains 2 columns.

```
{
  AcctNum  (nchar(30), null),
  DataInfo (nchar(745), null)
}
```

While I don't care the data in the DataInfo column, I do want to add about 10k of row into the table with unique AcctNum on each row.

The problem though is I need to keep the length of the data in both column. For example, AcctNum column looks like "400000000000001               ". how do I increment the number while keep the "blank space"?

Not sure if I make much sense here, but please let me know and I will try to explain more, thanks!

Comment: Am I correct if I think you want the range of AcctNum to be between 400000000000001 and 400000000010001 ?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!!! Yup, all I want is each AcctNum to be unique. So this would work too!

Comment: And what do you want? A procedure to insert all those rows? [Have you tried anything?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a recursive common table expression :

```
-- set up a table variable for demo purpose

declare @t table (AcctNum nchar(30) null, DataInfo nchar(745) null);
-- insert the starting value
insert @t values ('400000000000001', null);

-- run the cte to generate the sequence
with cte (acctnum, num) as (
    select acctnum, cast(acctnum as bigint) + 1 num  -- starting value
    from @t
    union all
    select acctnum, num+1 from cte
    where num < cast(acctnum as bigint) + 10000      -- stopping value
    )

-- insert data sequence into the table
insert @t (AcctNum, DataInfo)
select num, null from cte
option (maxrecursion 10000);

select * from @t;
```

The table variable **@t** will now contain acctnum 400000000000001 -> 400000000010001 as a contiguous sequence.

Comment: Thanks jpw, it works! And if you don't mind to bug you 1 more minute (for my own educational purposes), what kind of syntax is this "; with"?

Comment: @C.T. The semicolon is there to terminate the previous batch of statements (if any). From the documentation: _When a CTE is used in a statement that is part of a batch, the statement before it must be followed by a semicolon._ So it really belongs at the end of whatever is before, it's just common to add it to the start to be sure it's there :)